# How to retrieve a YouTube caption track

Tags: coldfusion

Can someone show me how to retrieve a YouTube caption track?
I'm reading [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions#Retrieve_Caption_Track), and I don't know where to begin.

Should I use a cfhttp command or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab it by copying from the web developers console.

I found it changing dynamically underneath #player .html5-video-player .html5-video-controls #caption-window-0
.caption-window-transform
.captions-text

Comment: Google Chrome developers tool.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would use cfhttp. You would first need to fetch information on the video itself. According to the docs, if a caption track exists, it's going to exist in the  tag. So look for that, and if it exists, you do a second cfhttp call to fetch it. This could be something we add to the [YoutubeCFC](http://youtubecfc.riaforge.org/) project as well.

Comment: Huh?  YoutubeCFC?  Furiously typing now!

Comment: Nice, I did not know about that one either. (Added a link to the answer)

Comment: No problem, and great idea for a cfc!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use class httpclient from java. create object of it and use can fetch information from social site. get more details on it.